# Android C# Button Click Password Generate

Tags: c#, android

I'm trying to create a simple password generate app with 4 checkboxes, I've previously used the same code starting from the below section of code in a C# Winform application where it works wonderfully.

**if (upper.Checked | lower.Checked | number.Checked | 
symbol.Checked)**

However, when trying the same code in my Android App I get an error on the below section stating that the string is incorrect.

int _len = Convert.ToInt32(txtPassword.Text);

What am I missing? Ps. I'm new to Android, but done some Winform work before

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace PasswordGenerator
{
[Activity(Label = "PasswordGenerator", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    CheckBox upper;
    CheckBox lower;
    CheckBox number;
    CheckBox symbol;
    TextView txtPassword;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnGenerate);
        txtPassword = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtPassword);
        upper = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.upper);
        lower = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.lower);
        number = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.number);
        symbol = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.symbol);

            button1.Click += (sender, e) => {
                string message = string.Empty;

                if (upper.Checked | lower.Checked | number.Checked | 
symbol.Checked)
                {
                    int _len = Convert.ToInt32(txtPassword.Text);
                    string _chars = "";
                    if (upper.Checked) _chars += "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                    if (lower.Checked) _chars += "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
                    if (number.Checked) _chars += "0123456789";
                    if (symbol.Checked) _chars += "~!@%$<>^&_-#";
                    var _rnd = new Random();
                    var _pass = new string(
                    Enumerable.Repeat(_chars, _len)
                    .Select(s => s[_rnd.Next(s.Length)])
                    .ToArray());
                    txtPassword.Text = _pass;
                }
                else
                {
                    message = ("Error: Please select one or more password 
options");
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the value of `txtPassword.Text` preferably from the debugger?=!

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `Length` property of `txtPassword.Text`: `int _len = Convert.ToInt32(txtPassword.Text.Length);`

But since `Length` is already an `int`, you don't need to convert it; just assign it to your variable: `int _len = txtPassword.Text.Length;`

Oh, and please don't instantiate a new `Random` each time you click the button. This could cause that you get the same number every time you click the button, if you click it rapidly.

Comment: Ok thanks, will give that go. In terms of the `random` part, is this just for Android, as this code is used in my winform application too and works just fine

Comment: No, this is not just for Android, but initializing `Random` once and then just calling `.Next()` could improve the app's performance since initializing `Random` is relatively expensive. You can read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I haven't actively been working on the app at the moment, when I do I will let you know :)